# Writing to <head> in ClientBehaviorRenderer

Tags: jsf

I am currently playing around with JSFs ClientBehavior API.
I want to create a client behavior that uses jQuery. Besides inclusion of the *.js files for jQuery another script will be required in the `<head>` section to bootstrap all the jQuery stuff i.e. create client side widgests.

I tried to follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586629/custom-jsf-component-which-adds-new-child-to-page-head-facet/4919852#4919852) from victor herrera, but the component system event is never processed. I guess this is because ClientBehaviors do not inherit from UIComponent.

So my question is how to add dynamically created JS to the `<head>` of the rendered document.

This is what the rendered output in the end should look like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        // Dynamically created stuff here 
   }   
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 ...
 <input type="text" id="myJSFInputWithClientBehavior" onclick="doSomeStuffWithjQuery()" />
</body>
</html>
```