# How to programmatically add JS and CSS resources to <h:head>

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, head

I need to add programmatically JavaScript and CSS resources to `<h:head>` of a JSF page. It isn't clear how to achieve this. How can I do it or is there a kickoff example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That depends on where exactly you'd like to declare the resource. *Normally*, the only reason to programmatically declare them is that you've a custom [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) or [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html) which generates HTML code which in turn requires those JS and/or CSS resources. They are then to be declared by [`@ResourceDependency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceDependency.html) or [`@ResourceDependencies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceDependencies.html).

```
@ResourceDependency(library="mylibrary", name="foo.css")
public class FooComponentWithCSS extends UIComponentBase {
    // ...
}
```

```java
@ResourceDependencies({
    @ResourceDependency(library="mylibrary", name="bar.css"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="mylibrary", name="bar.js")
})
public class BarComponentWithCSSandJS extends UIComponentBase {
    // ...
}
```

But if you *really* need to declare them elsewhere, such as in a backing bean method which is invoked *before* render response (otherwise it's simply too late), then you can do that by [`UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#addComponentResource%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29). The component resource must be created as an [`UIOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html) having a renderer type of `javax.faces.resource.Script` or `javax.faces.resource.Stylesheet`, to represent a fullworthy `<h:outputScript>` or `<h:outputStylesheet>` respectively. The `library` and `name` attributes can just be put in the attribute map.

```
UIOutput css = new UIOutput();
css.setRendererType("javax.faces.resource.Stylesheet");
css.getAttributes().put("library", "mylibrary");
css.getAttributes().put("name", "bar.css");

UIOutput js = new UIOutput();
js.setRendererType("javax.faces.resource.Script");
js.getAttributes().put("library", "mylibrary");
js.getAttributes().put("name", "bar.js");

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getViewRoot().addComponentResource(context, css, "head");
context.getViewRoot().addComponentResource(context, js, "head");
```

Comment: Here you find information where to place the declaration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586629

Comment: Great! This saved my day.

Comment: I was also struggling with where to add the declaration. I ended up adding it in the constructor of my UIComponent.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Any method which is invoked *before* render response suffices. Inside an `UIComponent` you'd usually hook on `PostAddToViewEvent` or perhaps `PreRenderViewEvent` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script and style resources to a page like this:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "xxxx.js";
head.appendChild(s);

s = document.createElement("style");
s.type = "text/css"
s.src = "yyy.css";
head.appendChild(s);
```

Or, in function form:

```
function addScript(path) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = path;
    head.appendChild(s);
}

function addCSSFile(path) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var s = document.createElement("style");
    s.type = "text/css";
    s.src = path;
    head.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: Although this is valid when used in JavaScript, this does not help in a JSF context.