# JSF ui:include on mojarra gives "One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view."

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I'm loading achild `*.xhtml` file in my jsf page with `ui:include`. When I load this

```
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    Testing
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this error
    One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.

However - when I modify it to this:

```
<html>
  <!-- <head/> -->
  <body>
    Testing
  </body>
</html>
```

The error goes away. (The child *.xhtml file comes from a static content team so it can't have jsf directives in it).

What is the root cause? How can this be avoided?

Versions:

- Mojarra 2.0
- Java 7.0
- Tomcat 7.0
- Windows 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's talking about the [`<h:head>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/head.html). Do the same for the body, which should be [`<h:body>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/body.html).

By the way, the generated HTML output must be syntactically valid. You usually don't put `<html>` in an **include** file, but only in the parent file or the master template.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)
- [What's the difference between <h:head> and <head> in Java Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028105/whats-the-difference-between-hhead-and-head-in-java-facelets/6044008#6044008)
- [How to programmatically add JS and CSS resources to <h:head>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451397/how-to-programmatically-add-js-and-css-resources-to-hhead/12451778#12451778)