# One or more resources has the target of 'head' but not 'head' component has been defined within the view

Tags: user-interface, jsf, primefaces, head

I created a JSF page with PrimeFaces components. The project runs fine, but the PrimeFaces UI look and feel is completely missing. I'm only noticing below message in server log:

> One or more resources has the target of 'head' but not 'head' component has been defined within the view

What does this mean and how can I fix the PrimeFaces UI styling?

Answer (score 34):

This means that you're using plain HTML `<head>` instead of JSF `<h:head>` in your XHTML template. The JSF `<h:head>` allows automatic inclusion of CSS/JS resources in the generated HTML `<head>` via `@ResourceDependency` annotations. PrimeFaces as being a jQuery based JSF component library needs to auto-include some jQuery/UI JS/CSS files and this really requires a `<h:head>`.

So, search for a

```html
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    ...
</head>
```

in your templates and replace it by

```html
<h:head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    ...
</h:head>
```

#### See also:

- [What's the difference between <h:head> and <head> in Java Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028105/whats-the-difference-between-hhead-and-head-in-java-facelets/)
- [Unable to understand <h:head> behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452551/unable-to-understand-hhead-behaviour/)
- [How to programmatically add JS and CSS resources to <h:head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451397/how-to-programmatically-add-js-and-css-resources-to-hhead/)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Comment: OK, now the error message disappeared but PrimeFaces and Crud still run separately!

Comment: Just press "Ask Question" button to ask a question about that if you need answers. The current question has already been answered.