# ICEfaces configured for view /index.xhtml but h:head and h:body components are required

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am trying to integrate the ICEFaces ACE component library in my project. I've the following view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>

<h:outputStylesheet library="org.icefaces.component.skins"
    name="rime.css" />

<f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg" />
<title>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.templateTitle}" />
</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h:form>
            <ace:dataTable var="user" value="#{userBean.users}"
                paginator="true" rows="50" selectionMode="multiple">
                <ace:column headerText="users">
                    <ace:row>#{user}</ace:row>
                </ace:column>
            </ace:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately apparently there is no JavaScript / CSS loaded, so the components are not displayed properly. Moreover, the server logs this:

> ICEfaces configured for view /index.xhtml but h:head and h:body components are required

Is this related?

Comment: Why don't you show code in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) flavor? When one would copy'n'paste'n'run the code unmodified in order to try to reproduce your problem on a blank playground project, the runtime would complain that the `template.xhtml` is missing.

Comment: Good point, I adapted my question. Hope it is more understandable now...

Comment: Didn't you see a warning in server logs which says like *"One or more resources has the target of 'head' but not 'head' component has been defined within the view"*?

Comment: I can see a warning saying "ICEfaces configured for view /index.xhtml but h:head and h:body components are required". Is this what you  mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSF `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` components instead of plain HTML `<head>` and `<body>`. This way JSF and any JSF component library will be able to programmatically auto-include CSS/JS resources in there.

E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg" />

    <h:head>
        <title>#{msg.templateTitle}</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        ...
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Note that this way you also don't need that `<h:outputStylesheet>` anymore.

#### See also:

- [One or more resources has the target of 'head' but not 'head' component has been defined within the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940644/one-or-more-resources-has-the-target-of-head-but-not-head-component-has-been)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you'd better declare `resources.application` as `<resource-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml`, so that you don't need to repeat it over all views. Also note that you don't necessarily need `<h:outputText>` over all place. The `<head>` and all of above also indicates that you're learning JSF based on a JSF 1.x targeted tutorial instead of a 2.x targeted one. Make sure that you're using the right resources to learn.