# how i can resolve the head target in primefaces

Tags: jsf, view

i'm working on a project in jee with jsf and when i run a view This writing appears red

> [One or more resources share the "head" target, but no "head" component
>   has been defined in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDopP.png)

### *[click here forthe screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0pzd.png)*

thank you

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in that language.

Comment: yaah i know but this how the erreur show in the view please check the picture

Comment: Then you need to translate the message to English. This is an English language site.

Comment: OK , this is the erreur message :                                                                       One or more resources share the "head" target, but no "head" component has been defined in the view

Comment: Please [edit] your question

Comment: i edit my question please any ideas

Comment: Post the error in aearchengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit `<head> </head> to <h:head> </h:head>`

Comment: yaaah this is the problem thank you Haroun Gazzah problem resolve

Comment: @KhalidZahid: as could have been read on the duplicate in the 'related' section on the right (if you work on a pc) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940644/one-or-more-resources-has-the-target-of-head-but-not-head-component-has-been