# p:dataTable is not displaying while the value is fetched from the bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Im trying to populate a dataTable but its not even showing in the browser and i think im doing everything right.

I debugged and search al lot for this problem but couldn't fine anything that help me out.

If any of you can help me, that would be great

This is my table

```
    <h:form>
        <div class="tablaStock">
            <p:dataTable var="stock" value="#{empresaFarmaciaBeanDTT.empresas}">
                <p:column headerText="Code">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stock.direccion}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{stock.departamento}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

My bean

```
@ManagedBean(name ="empresaFarmaciaBeanDTT")
@SessionScoped
public class EmpresaFarmaciaBeanDT implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5356325535158861445L;
    @EJB
    private ControladorEmpresaFarmaciaRemote controlador;
    private List<EmpresaFarmacia> empresas = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void obtenerTodasEmpresasFarmacias() {
        try {
            empresas = controlador.obtenerTodasEmpresaFarmacia();
            System.out.println(empresas.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Hubo un error al crear obtenerTodasEmpresasFarmacias");
            System.out.println("Clase: EmpresaFarmaciaBean");
            System.out.println("Metodo: obtenerTodasEmpresasFarmacias");
            System.out.println("****************************");
        }

    }

    public List<EmpresaFarmacia> getEmpresas() {
        return empresas;
    }

    public void setEmpresas(List<EmpresaFarmacia> empresas) {
        this.empresas = empresas;
    }

}
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="empresa_farmacia")
@NamedQuery(name="EmpresaFarmacia.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM EmpresaFarmacia e")
public class EmpresaFarmacia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idempresaFarmacia;

    private String departamento;

    private String direccion;

    private String localidad;

    private String nombreFantasia;

    private String razonSocial;

    private String rut;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Usuario
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idUsuarioAsociado")
    private Usuario usuario;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TransaccionStockFarmacia
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="empresaFarmacia")
    private List<TransaccionStockFarmacia> transaccionStockFarmacias;

    public EmpresaFarmacia() {
    }

    public int getIdempresaFarmacia() {
        return this.idempresaFarmacia;
    }

    public void setIdempresaFarmacia(int idempresaFarmacia) {
        this.idempresaFarmacia = idempresaFarmacia;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return this.departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return this.direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return this.localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getNombreFantasia() {
        return this.nombreFantasia;
    }

    public void setNombreFantasia(String nombreFantasia) {
        this.nombreFantasia = nombreFantasia;
    }

    public String getRazonSocial() {
        return this.razonSocial;
    }

    public void setRazonSocial(String razonSocial) {
        this.razonSocial = razonSocial;
    }

    public String getRut() {
        return this.rut;
    }

    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return this.usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario1) {
        this.usuario = usuario1;
    }
```

And the result of the getEmpresas() in my Bean EmpresaFarmaciaBeanDT

[image]

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940644/one-or-more-resources-has-the-target-of-head-but-not-head-component-has-been

Comment: Thanks, but i'm actually using <h:head> & <h:body> tags.

Comment: "but its not even showing in the browser" what do you see?

Comment: i found what was wrong. My web.xml file have an incorrect caracther. I fix that and everything works just fine right now.