# Why does <p:galleria> tell me that the resource cannot be found or served on primefaces 11.0.0?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use the primefaces component <p:galleria> but when the application displays no image is shown, what it shows me in the Glassfish output is: JSF1064: resource not found or served.

This is xhtml

```html
<html>
<h:body>
        <h:form id="form1">
            <div class="card">
                <p:galleria value="#{galleriaView.photos}" var="photo" numVisible="5" responsiveOptions="#{galleriaView.responsiveOptions1}"
                        circular="true" autoPlay="true" transitionInterval="2000" style="max-width: 640px">
                    <p:graphicImage name="#{photo.itemImageSrc}" alt="#{photo.alt}" style="width: 100%; display: block;" />
                    <f:facet name="thumbnail">
                        <p:graphicImage name="#{photo.thumbnailImageSrc}" alt="#{photo.alt}" style="display: block;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:galleria>
            </div>
</h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is Photo.java

```java
public class Photo implements Serializable {
    
    private String itemImageSrc;
    private String thumbnailImageSrc;
    private String alt;
    private String title;

    public Photo() {
    }

    public Photo(String itemImageSrc, String thumbnailImageSrc, String alt, String title) {
        this.itemImageSrc = itemImageSrc;
        this.thumbnailImageSrc = thumbnailImageSrc;
        this.alt = alt;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getItemImageSrc() {
        return itemImageSrc;
    }

    public void setItemImageSrc(String itemImageSrc) {
        this.itemImageSrc = itemImageSrc;
    }

    public String getThumbnailImageSrc() {
        return thumbnailImageSrc;
    }

    public void setThumbnailImageSrc(String thumbnailImageSrc) {
        this.thumbnailImageSrc = thumbnailImageSrc;
    }

    public String getAlt() {
        return alt;
    }

    public void setAlt(String alt) {
        this.alt = alt;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }   
}
```

This is PhotoService.java

```java
public class PhotoService implements Serializable{
        
    private List<Photo> photos;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        photos = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("ALFRED: " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName());
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner1.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner1s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero1", "banner 1"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner2.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner2s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero2", "banner 2"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner3.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner3s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero3", "banner 3"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner4.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner4s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero4", "banner 4"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner5.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner5s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero5", "banner 5"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner6.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner6s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero6", "banner 6"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner7.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner7s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero7", "banner 7"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner8.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner8s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero8", "banner 8"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner9.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner9s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero9", "banner 9"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner10.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner10s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero10", "banner 10"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner11.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner11s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero11", "banner 11"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner12.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner12s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero12", "banner 12"));
        photos.add(new Photo("/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner13.jpg", "/recursos/imagenes/banner/banner13s.jpg", "Mi burrito Sabanero13", "banner 13"));    
    }
    
    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }
}
```

This is GalleriaView.java

```java
public class GalleriaView implements Serializable{
 
    private List<Photo> photos;
    private List<ResponsiveOption> responsiveOptions1;
    private List<ResponsiveOption> responsiveOptions2;
    private List<ResponsiveOption> responsiveOptions3;

    private int activeIndex = 0;
    
    @Inject
    private PhotoService servicio;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        photos = servicio.getPhotos();
        
        responsiveOptions1 = new ArrayList<>();
        responsiveOptions1.add(new ResponsiveOption("102px", 5));
        responsiveOptions1.add(new ResponsiveOption("76px", 3));
        responsiveOptions1.add(new ResponsiveOption("56px", 1));

        responsiveOptions2 = new ArrayList<>();
        responsiveOptions2.add(new ResponsiveOption("1024px", 5));
        responsiveOptions2.add(new ResponsiveOption("960px", 4));
        responsiveOptions2.add(new ResponsiveOption("768px", 3));
        responsiveOptions2.add(new ResponsiveOption("560px", 1));

        responsiveOptions3 = new ArrayList<>();
        responsiveOptions3.add(new ResponsiveOption("1500px", 5));
        responsiveOptions3.add(new ResponsiveOption("1024px", 3));
        responsiveOptions3.add(new ResponsiveOption("768px", 2));
        responsiveOptions3.add(new ResponsiveOption("560px", 1));
        
    }
    
    public void changeActiveIndex() {
        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        this.activeIndex = Integer.valueOf(params.get("index"));
    }

    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public List<ResponsiveOption> getResponsiveOptions1() {
        return responsiveOptions1;
    }

    public List<ResponsiveOption> getResponsiveOptions2() {
        return responsiveOptions2;
    }

    public List<ResponsiveOption> getResponsiveOptions3() {
        return responsiveOptions3;
    }

    public int getActiveIndex() {
        return activeIndex;
    }

    public void setActiveIndex(int activeIndex) {
        this.activeIndex = activeIndex;
    }

    public void setServicio(PhotoService servicio) {
        this.servicio = servicio;
    }  
}
```

This is the output of glassfish:

Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner1s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner2s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner3s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner4s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner5s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner6s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner7s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner8s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner9s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner10s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner11s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner12s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, /recursos/imagenes/banner/banner13s.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner1.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner2.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner3.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner5.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner4.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner6.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner7.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner8.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner9.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner10.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner11.jpg.
Warning:   JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, recursos/imagenes/banner/banner12.jpg.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940644/one-or-more-resources-has-the-target-of-head-but-not-head-component-has-been and load the images from the correct path (see showcase).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).