# JSF resource (JavaScript) not rendered using addComponentResource

Tags: jsf, resources, uicomponents

I'm on Mojarra 2.2.13 and my project uses PrimeFaces 6.0.

I'm writing my own JSF `UIComponent`. It requires a bit of JavaScript located in `webapp/resources/js/charts.min.js`. When I annotate my component using `@ResourceDependency` the script **is** rendered:

```
@ResourceDependency(name = "js/charts.min.js", target = "head")
```

But, I don't always need it to be rendered. So I was trying to conditionally add a component resource to the view root from within the `encodeBegin(FacesContext context)` method:

```
if (condition) {
  UIOutput js = new UIOutput();
  js.setRendererType("javax.faces.resource.Script");
  js.getAttributes().put("name", "js/charts.min.js");
  context.getViewRoot().addComponentResource(context, js, "head");

  writer.startElement("div", null);
  writer.writeAttribute("class", "myChart", null);
  // ... write chart data
  writer.endElement("div");
}
```

This does **not** render the script (`myChart` **is** rendered though). No errors appear in my log. Any ideas what I could check or improve?

I've also tested without PrimeFaces (not sure if its head renderer was causing this), but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you try the <c:if test="#{myBean.isRendered}"> jstl tag instead of the java code settings?

Comment: @TheBitman no. How is that helpful when creating a UIComponent?

Comment: I thought maybe you could filter js LINK in the JSF file instead of the component. But tell the truth I don't understand your question totally :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `encodeBegin(FacesContext context)` is not the correct location to add resources. You are too late there.

I've moved the code to the **constructor** of the component and now the script is added. I'm not 100% this is the best location to do so, but I've seen component libraries doing it in the constructor as well. It also works together with PrimeFaces.

See also:

- [How to programmatically add JS and CSS resources to <h:head>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451397/how-to-programmatically-add-js-and-css-resources-to-hhead)